# Unable to select element paragraph using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paragraph, pre

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p").click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });

});
  function func(){
var s = "<p id=" + id +">"+"<center>"+"<h2><b>Topic :</b></h2>"+message+"</center></p><br>";
document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML+=s;

}
</script>



</head>
<body>
//call function func
<pre id="stat" > </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Guys the function func is supposed to create a paragraph with id as "id " and the content as a message inside the  tag with id as "stat " .. it works fine 
But i cant use the 'Jquery' selector to use the click function on

tag :/ !
the reason i am inserting  inside in  is i need the interpreter to consider "\n" as a new line.
Why is that , not working ?

and is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: where is the `<p>` tag in your code?

Comment: have you checked for js console errors? i'm asking because id and message are undefined

Comment: There are 6 answers, and they will all work. Create a jsfiddle and edit your question.

Comment: @arun15thmay Yeah actually i have defined inside the fuction its just a rough sketch over here

Comment: I agree with @johnnycardy. Can you please create a jsfiddle. It can be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('click','p',function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 'p', function() { $(this).hide();})
```

The code you wrote is not working because the p element is not present when the document is loaded. Since the p element is dynamically added, you have to attach the event to the document object

Answer (score 0):

Attach the click event handler inside `func`:

```
function func(){
    var s = "<p id=" + id +">"+"<center>"+"<h2><b>Topic :</b></h2>"+message+"</center></p><br>";
    document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML+=s;


    $("#" + id).click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

Or better still:

```
function func(){
    var s = $("<p id=" + id +">"+"<center>"+"<h2><b>Topic :</b></h2>"+message+"</center></p><br>");
    $("#stat").append(s);

    s.click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: u mean like <p onclick="somefunction();" >??

Comment: You could do that, but it's cleaner to attach with jQuery.

Comment: @jonnycardy Doesnt seem to work the way it need to be 
As i have 

contents of the function in a for loop to add it 100 times with diff id and messages but  i just get one paragraph instead of 100

Comment: Ah...if there's 100 of them then my answer wouldn't be particularly efficient anyway. I would go for a variation on @arun15thmay answer.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way will be to change

```
var s = "<p id=" + id +">"+"<center>"+"<h2><b>Topic :</b></h2>"+message+"</center></p><br>";
```

to

```
var s = "<p id=" + id +" onclick=\"$(this).hide()\">"+"<center>"+"<h2><b>Topic :</b></h2>"+message+"</center></p><br>";
```

and delete this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p").click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
$('body').on('click', 'p', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.on()` instead

```
 $(document).on('click', 'p', function(){
     $(this).hide();
  });
```

`.on()` has to ability to add a click handler to elements that are created dynamically , like your `<p>` tags are

Comment: Didnt work Bro :/ ., But thank For giving me an idea about the prob :)

Comment: @DhayalanPro - this will work , either the HTML is not getting added properly , or you have some javascript syntax errors somewhere preventing this code from working.  Try looking in the console for other errors

Comment: Sure Ill check it out